# Java program to restrict websites

Tags: java, url, browser, restrict

I WANT TO WRITE A PROGRAM IN JAVA THAT RESTRICTS CERTAIN WEBSITES FROM BEING OPEN IN MY BROWSER... how can i do that ? or is it even can be done in java (concerning JVM i mean)

Comment: Why the shouting? and what have you tried?

Comment: i don't know where to start... coz it seems that i need access to the browser or something else... which i dnt know and can't find

Comment: you might want to configure proxy and controll allowed site from there, there are already tools available why you need to rewrite?

Comment: You [asked the same question just a few minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981054/what-happens-inside-when-i-restrict-a-website-in-a-browser).

Comment: thx found what i was looking for... seems that the site can be blocked by editing the hostfile in systems file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to block web pages for only a certain web browser or all of them?
If you want to block access to a certain webpage consider editing the [Host File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) manually